# How to bind generic list of objects to a MonoDroid GridView

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to bind List with 5 properties (columns) and 10 rows of data to a GridView. The examples I found all have an ImageAdapter.

How do you bind object properties from a list to the GridView? What kind of Adapter do I need?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this help you, but when i need a custom control I set all the information inflating a custom axml, if you are used to a WindowsPhone or a Windows 8 application, it's like a User Control

```
        LinearLayout linearImages = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LinearLayoutImages);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)LayoutInflater.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);

        foreach (Image image in images)
        {
            var view = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ImageControl, null);

            TextView txtView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
            txtView.Text = image.Title;

            ...

            linearImages.AddView(view);
       }
```